# Magento 2 - Create also symlink to .css

Tags: magento2, less, grunt, static-content-deploy

I have managed to successfully install Magento 2 with a downloaded theme after many hours of struggling... Now I'm facing the symlink issue.

I've installed everything, php intl extension, grunt, nodejs but when I use "grunt exec:claue" it will delete all the files in the theme folder and only creates a symlink to "custom.less" (the file I've added to load in the header via default_head_blocks.xml). Then I got this in the css folder:

[image: Only 1 symlink to the custom.css]

After that I have to run "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL" to get all the other files deployed, but what I got then is this:

[image]
You can see that only the "custom.less" is a symlink to the original file...

I'm in Developer mode so I really don't know anymore what I can do. I just need the "custom.css" to be a symlink also to make some customizations to the styling.

Version: Magento 2.1.7

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

**Magento dosen't creates symlink of custom.css because it creates this file through compilation. Means custom.css does not exist in real path, so it is not possible to generate its symlink**

- You will get symlinks of files which are really exist in magento .

Comment: So it's not possible to add a extra stylesheet for development so you don't have to compile everything when you change something in CSS?